# Why can't Theme.Holo be resolved as a Theme? 

Tags: android

I used `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:maxSdkVersion="15" />` but Theme.Holo doesnot work.

Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Login" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Eclipse Error or Android SDK Error?

Comment: For one thing, you shouldn't be using maxSdkVersion unless there is a reason for it, and a second thing, you don't seem to have a targetSdkVersion specified. Fix these issues first.

Comment: The HOLO theme is only available in api 11 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html), the Theme you're referencing doesn't exist.

In this case, it's called `Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen`, not `Theme_Holo_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` (ActionBar in Honeycomb is basically the same as a TitleBar pre-Honeycomb)

By the way, do not let the underscores confuse you. In this documentation, when you see an underscore, you're suppose to replace it with a dot `.`

Also, be sure to target the api level 11 or higher, or it won't find it since this kind of theme was only introduced in Honeycomb.

Comment: Ok, can you open your Problems View?

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name (at'theme' with value @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen)

Comment: Ok. Replace Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen with Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: Why does it not exist? Its the Holo Theme

Comment: I don't know, please check screen shoot

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Are you getting the same error with @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen What's the error now?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" is ok.

Comment: That was an excellent question @Ahmad, I just found out why I think. It's because it's called the action bar in the Holo theme. For instance, this theme exists Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen

Comment: Yes, Ahmad, I already told ArnoHlaMoe to target api level 11, but apparently that wasn't enough, so I edited my answer. Hopefully, ArnoHlaMoe has kept this change.

Comment: Now, I got it. Thanks Stephan Branczyk :D